# Restrict editing of specific portion in Word File using POI

Tags: apache-poi

I've a requirement in which I've to restrict user from editing specific paragraphs in the word file .
I tried using Apache POI but I'm not able to figure out how to do it .
I was able to find the class " import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPermStart " can be used , but eclipse says  " The import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPermStart can't be resolved"
I'm using  Apache POI-Version: 3.9.

Comment: You will need [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas) `jar`. Should be version `1.1` for that old `apache poi 3.9`. But why are you using such an old version of `apache poi`?

Comment: @Axel Richter I also checked the latest -Version: 4.1.1 . I was not able to find " CTPermStart " class . Is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: As said, you will need `ooxml-schemas` `jar`.

Comment: Yes I've ooxml-schemas.jar in build path,it's  still not working . I checked the jar using decompiler . I was not able to find  CTPermStart.class

Comment: For me [ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1) (for `apache poi 3.9`) as well as [ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4) (for `apache poi 4.1.1`) contains that class.

Comment: Ok , I'll check ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar . Thank man .